# One to one relationship Error on Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, java-17

I would like to seek your insights regarding the error I'm encountering with my postgresql commands.

Basically, what I want to achieve is to create a "booking" entity with one to one relationship to another table called "booking details". But flyway won't migrate my schema with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.FlywaySqlScriptException:
Migration V0__Initial.sql failed
--------------------------------
SQL State  : 42S02
Error Code : 42102
Message    : Table "BOOKING_DETAILS" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE booking ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BOOKING_ON_BOOKING_DETAILS FOREIGN KEY (booking_details_id) REFERENCES booking_details (booking_entity_id) [42102-214]
Line       : 16
Statement  : ALTER TABLE booking ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BOOKING_ON_BOOKING_DETAILS FOREIGN KEY (booking_details_id) REFERENCES booking_details (booking_entity_id)
```

Here is my postgresql commands:

```
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS booking_transaction_sequence;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS booking;

CREATE SEQUENCE  IF NOT EXISTS booking_transaction_sequence START WITH 1000 INCREMENT BY 100;

CREATE TABLE booking (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL,
   booking_number VARCHAR(255),
   booking_status VARCHAR(255),
   processed_by VARCHAR(255),
   created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
   booking_details_id BIGINT,
   CONSTRAINT pk_booking PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE booking ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BOOKING_ON_BOOKING_DETAILS FOREIGN KEY (booking_details_id) REFERENCES booking_details (booking_entity_id);

DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS booking_details_transaction_sequence;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS booking_details;
CREATE SEQUENCE  IF NOT EXISTS booking_details_transaction_sequence START WITH 1000 INCREMENT BY 100;

CREATE TABLE booking_details (
  booking_entity_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
   sender_name VARCHAR(255),
   item_details VARCHAR(255),
   pickup_address VARCHAR(255),
   rider_name VARCHAR(255),
   delivery_address VARCHAR(255),
   cancellation_reason VARCHAR(255),
   CONSTRAINT pk_booking_details PRIMARY KEY (booking_entity_id)
);

ALTER TABLE booking_details ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BOOKING_DETAILS_ON_BOOKINGENTITY FOREIGN KEY (booking_entity_id) REFERENCES booking (id);
```

I would highly appreciate any inputs regarding this. Thank you.

I tried using the "extend" method on my BookingDetails entity to BookingEntity. This run my java springboot application but for some reason I can't fetch data with internal error 500 in postman. So I change my sql commands with the one-to-one relationship mapping but I got the above errors.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to reference non-existent "booking_details" table when you ALTER booking to ADD CONSTRAINT. You can move that command after "booking_details" table have been created.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of interest - how you're planning to insert new entries given the schema? In order to create booking you'd need to have booking_details created and vice versa.

Comment: Hi, I am new to relationship mapping, so any insightful correction would highly be appreciated. Basically for this project, my target is to get data from the booking number and booking status in the "BookingEntity" and at the same time the data from the "BookingDetailsEntity" will be shown along side with the aforementioned query. Hence, I tried using the one-to-one relationship approach. Do you think this is okay in this scenario?

Comment: Assuming 'booking' being the "central" table, you reference to it from the dependent table e.g. 'booking_details', but 'booking' table shouldn't have any relationships to 'booking_details'. One-to-one is enforced by the PRIMARY KEY on 'booking_details' being  also FOREIGN KEY referencing 'booking'. To make the solution future proof, I would consider splitting/denormalising 'booking_details' into meaningful tables 'delivery', 'recipient' etc.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: put this command on the last part of the sql so that the two tables must be created first before it can be altered.

"ALTER TABLE booking ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BOOKING_ON_BOOKING_DETAILS FOREIGN KEY (booking_details_id) REFERENCES booking_details (booking_entity_id);"